# Trying to learn JDA(Java Discord API), and this showed up but there's no errors in my code

Tags: java, discord, discord-jda

This is what's showing in the
[image: console].

Here are the codes.

[image: main class]

[image: commands class]

I havent really implemented any commands for the bot yet, but im just curious why it isnt working and how to fix it.

Comment: Please don't post code as images.

Comment: oh im sorry ahaha its my first time thanks for letting me know

Answer (score 3):

You imported the wrong EventListener. JDA uses [`net.dv8tion.jda.api.hooks.EventListener`](https://ci.dv8tion.net/job/JDA/javadoc/net/dv8tion/jda/api/hooks/EventListener.html) not `okhttp3.EventListener`. You also typo'd received and you tried to use `onGuildMessageReceived` which requires using `@Override` and `extends ListenerAdapter`

```java
public class MyListener extends ListenerAdapter {
  @Override
  public void onGuildMessageReceived(GuildMessageReceivedEvent event) {
    code here
  }
}
```

By the way, if you do `split(" ")` there is a 0% chance that any of the array elements will contain a space. So `args[0].equals(prefix + " " + "test")` is always false.